# Wrap entire column in a div using Typoscript

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

I have a normal and a left column, and want to wrap them each in a div. What's the correct Typoscript for this? I can only find code for wrapping each *element* in something. This is what I've got so far:

```
page = PAGE
page.typeNum = 0

page.10 < styles.content.get

page.20 < styles.content.getLeft

// Wrong, will wrap every object, not hole column.
page.20.renderObj.stdWrap.wrap = <div id="left-column"> | </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply put a wrap around the individual columns, they behave like a [COA](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/ContentObjects/CoaAndCoaInt/Index.html#cobj-coa)

```
page.20.wrap = <div id="left-column"> | </div>
```

Comment: I think I tried that, but later discovered I made a typo (`pages` instead of `page`). Will check again tomorrow at work.